# What does 'scope' mean in the context of a Salesforce report? Where/how is it specified? What are the possible (API) values?

Tags: rest-api, reporting, custom-report-type, reports-api

There is a method called `getScope()` in [ReportMetadata Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm). Can someone please shed some light on what 'Scope' actually means? Where/how is it specified? What are the possible (API/system-digestible) values?

**Per documentation:**

> Returns the API name for the scope defined for the report. Scope
>   values depend on the report type.

**Background:**

I am trying to update report metadata via [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_save_report.htm). Upon GET, I see that the metadata returns something called  `"scope":"organization"` in JSON. After making a couple column API name changes, I POST the request back to save changes to server. Sadly, I get an error response saying `"scope":"organization"` is invalid. Because I couldn't find much documentation around it, I did some random GETs on other reports and noticed that some returned `"scope":"team"` instead. I then tried updating a report that has `"scope":"organization"` with `"scope":"team"` and it worked without complaining. Now I am worried if that is OK to do? I am hoping this doesn't cause more grief than good. I don't see any *visual* differences in the report after the change, though. Thoughts?

**UPDATE 1:**

I just figured that 'Scope' relates to a report being public or private. [More info here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm).

> **Supported Query Scopes**
>
> Use these scopes to help specify the data your
>   SOQL query returns.
>
> **allPrivate** Records saved in all users’ private folders. Requires the
>   user permission "Manage All Private Reports and Dashboards" and
>   Enhanced Analytics Folder Sharing. If your organziation was created
>   after the Summer ’13 release, you already have Enhanced Analytics
>   Folder Sharing. Available in API version 36.0 and later.
>
> **created** Records created by the user running the query.
>
> **everything** All
>   records except records saved in other users’ private folders.
>
> **mine**
>   Records saved in the private folder of the user running the query.
>
> **organizationOwned** Records saved in Unfiled Public Reports. In
>   Lightning Experience, the Unfiled Public Reports folder is called
>   Public Reports.

But now, how do I know the actual value to pass to the REST API endpoint? Like I mentioned above, the values from what I gathered based on the reports in our org so far are `organization`, `team`, `useronly` (definitely not an exhaustive list).

**UPDATE 2:**

[Here is more on Scope.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_using_scope.htm) I now see 'Team' in there, but no 'Organization'...?! What is the difference between [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_using_scope.htm) and [Supported Query Scopes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm) I linked to above?

Comment: The specific words (e.g. organization vs organizationOwned) might be API version dependent. What happens if you try versions 45.0 and probably 37.0 or 32.0? Any difference?

Comment: Wow... the same action on the same report in different versions returned different error messages: v39.0 = "organization is not a valid scope."

v45.0 = "The column BucketField_62445055 is not a valid column., sourceColumnName could not be found. It is either not a valid column api name or you do not have access to this column., organization is not a valid scope., For the filter 6: Specify a valid filterable column because BucketField_62445055 is invalid."

v37.0 = "The clone request must contain a valid cloneId parameter."

v32.0 = "HTTP Method 'POST' not allowed. Allowed are GET"